# How to disable a screen by spinner on Android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

Have a spinner include two choice: Yes/No and a button
If select Yes on spinner and click Save button, the Login screen before will be disabled. App will enter main screen.
Else, the login will enable.
Please help me! thanks

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()).equals("yes"))
                    {

                        //login screen is disable

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Login screen is enable
                    }
```

Comment: above code are in login Screen??? or before login screen?? explain in detail.

Comment: This code is in onClick function when clicked on save button.

Answer (score 1):

used the android:visiblity .....

Comment: Please let us know what you want by "Login screen will disable" because I think Sachin's sloution is fine, you should either disable or make invisible the login button which'll make your login activity as disable.

Comment: sorry!!! "login screen will be disabled" -edited.
Login screen will launch when running the application.
Now I want to build an option to either remain the login screen or  it is disabled when selecting the spinner.